# Can't deal with ListView

Tags: android

In my `ListView` ,the Item have `Switch` activity. When the Items are overflow the screen, have to slide to show top or bottom item .then ,the Switch of items on top or bottom will  change the state automatically and response state change of events.the more item hide behind the screen ,the more change happen.I don't know how to solve

Is there anyone can help?thanks a lot.

**I have update the code on**

**code:**

```
private class MAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
    {
        super(context, c, true);

        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_task_list_item, null);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        final MZTask task = new MZTask(cursor);

        // ic
        ImageView ic = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_action_ic);
        ic.setImageResource(task.getIcId());

        // action name
        TextView actionName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_action_name);
        actionName.setText(task.getActionName(context));

        // time
        TextView time = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_task_time);
        time.setText(task.getTimeString());

        // repeat
        TextView repeat = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_task_repeat);
        repeat.setText(task.getDayStringOfWeek(context));

        // switch view
        final Switch stch = (Switch) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_task_switch);
        stch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(getCheckedChangeListener(task));
        stch.setChecked(task.state());

        // list more
        RelativeLayout icLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_more);
        icLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                popUpMenu(task);
            }
        });

        // ..
        RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.main_list_layout_switch);
        itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stch.setChecked(!stch.isChecked());
            }
        });

    }

    public OnCheckedChangeListener getCheckedChangeListener(
            final MZTask task)
    {
        return new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                    boolean change)
            {
                if (change)
                    task.startTask(context, dbAdapter);
                else
                    task.cancelTask(context, dbAdapter);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your adapter's getView method here. Chances are you aren't setting the switch's state for the requested position as the views are recycled.